# JQuery Sortable - Handle bug in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, z-index, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of divs that I want to be able to sort. Each div has text in it, and also a handle inside of it (due to the UI, I only want to sort if the left half of the list item is dragged). In Chrome/FireFox this works great, but in IE if you click on the text it won't let you sort, even though the text is within the handle.

I have a stripped down mockup of the problem here, make sure you use Internet Explorer to test: http://jsfiddle.net/t8Ebd/

I'm assuming this is a layering thing, but have tried the following approaches with no luck:

- Changing z-indexes of text and handle
- $(".itemname").disableSelection();​​​​
- ms-user-select: none; user-select:none;
- adding the text class to the list of handles - this solves the problem, but will not work for me since I don't want the text on the right half of the list item to trigger sorting
- Setting background color on the handle - I know this sounds weird, but if I set a color then it becomes the top most element and thus acts correctly, although it hides the text which won't work for me.

Anyone have any other ideas??

Comment: alternate workaround: put a bunch of `&nbsp;` in the handle tag div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got an extra comma after ".sorthandle" that breaks in IE:

```
$("ul").sortable({
    handle: ".sorthandle",  // here
});
```

Change it to:

```
$("ul").sortable({
    handle: ".sorthandle"
});
```

---

I have suggested in the comment to use the method `disableSelection()` from jQuery UI. Although it does not seem to quite work neither.

I have managed to achieve what you're after by setting a background-color to the handle and the opacity to zero so it's invisible:

```
.sorthandle {
    ...
    background-color: White;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WBY6x/)**

Of course this removes your green border, I don't know if this is important or not.

Maybe this would work by using a png transparent background-image. My guess is that the handle having no background, IE selects the text underneath.

Comment: Well it works for me in IE 7 > 9... Do you have an error in the javascript console ?

Comment: no, I used your code, no error - if you click the text on the left side and drag, it hightlights the text; does not drag - good catch on the comma though !

Comment: The plugin offers a method `disableSelection()` to avoid this kind of situation. I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses - nice comma catch, although I'm still seeing the root issue on the latest demo you provided. I see that you're disabling selection of the text, but if you drag the text sorting is not happening. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DidierGhys - I was looking at the opacity as well.  There IS a workaround to the border issue: put a span inside the handle with a single `&nbsp;` inside it and give it a display:block, 100% width; and the opacity css as you describe...kind of a hack though

Comment: Holy crap you're a genius! I never would have thought about making opacity 0. Tested to work in at least IE7+. Thanks Didier!

Comment: And yeah, don't worry about the border - I just put it on there for display purposes, it isn't part of the real UI.

Comment: You're very welcome. If I have a more structural solution, I'll come back here.

Answer (score 1):

change your layout to: (kind of a hack)

```
<div class='sorthandle'><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
```

and add this css:

```
 .sorthandle span{
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    opacity:0.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    display:block;
}
```

USE THIS IF you want to keep the border on the sorthandle

Comment: I do appreciate you working on keeping the border, but I had only added it in there to highlight the issue better. Thanks for the assist, Mark!